# Ruby on Rails using check_box_tag with nested attributes and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have 4 models

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :addendums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addendums
end

class Addendum < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :contract
  has_many :addendum_services
  has_many :services, through: :addendum_services
end

class AddendumService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addendum
  belongs_to :service
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addendum_services
end
```

I'm using nested attributes to build the addendum through the Contract's form and it's working for all the Addendum's attributes but I also want the user to chose, using the `check_box_tag`, the list of Services to use. Since the `Addendum` does not have an attribute for `addendum_services`, what should I add to the `Contract`'s strong params in order to accept the Service list? Also, how can I generate the list of services on the form? i'm currently using this:

```
<%= form_for(@contract) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :addendums do |addendums_form|%>
    <%= addendums_form.label 'Services'%><br>
    <% for serv in Service.all %>
    <%= check_box_tag "service[]", serv, @addendum.services.include?(serv) %>
    <%= serv %><br>
<% end %>
```

but it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

I am using a similar method but with Documents and Categories.

Consider a Document a Service

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorisations
```

A Category an Addendum

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :documents, :through => :categorisations
```

and an AddendumService a Categorisation

```
class Categorisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :category
```

Note: You are missing a through method for Service

```
has_many addendum, :through => :addendum_services
```

Additionally, my check box is as follows;

```
  - Category.all.in_groups_of(3,false) do |category_list|
    %tr
      - for categories in category_list
        %td
          = check_box_tag "categorisation[category_ids][]", categories.id, @document.categories.include?(categories)
          %label= categories.title
```

Note the "categorisation[category_ids][]" rather than "service[]" -> perhaps you need "addendum_service[:service][]" ?

Hopefully this allows you to adapt your code, or perhaps call me stupid and enhance my development.